# How do I change a raster's geotransform with GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, affine-transformation

I'm trying to use GDAL to set the geotransform of a new raster that I've created by following the steps outlined in the [GDAL API Tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html).

```
# create the new dataset
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
dataset = driver.Create('test_gt.tif', 60, 60, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

# check the default geotransform
print dataset.GetGeoTransform()  # prints (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)

# try to alter the geotransform and ensure that it has been set
dataset.SetGeoTransform([0,1,0,0,0,-1])
print dataset.GetGeoTransform()  # prints (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1)

dataset = None  # closes the dataset

# Try reopening the dataset now and see if the geotransform has been set.
ds = gdal.Open('test_gt.tif')
print ds.GetGeoTransform()  #prints (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

The dataset.SetGeoTransform() [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716155258/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALDataset.html#a0fe0f81d65d84557b5d71ddc024faa02) says that this should set the affine transformation coefficients (which, according to the `dataset.GetGeoTransform()` documentation is set to `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]` by default), but as you can see from my above code, the changes don't seem to actually take effect when I try to change them.

I've even tried flushing the new raster's cache to disk by `dataset.FlushCache()`, but this doesn't seem to save the changes either.

How can I have GDAL actually save the altered geotransform to disk?

I'm using GDAL version 1.6.3 installed from PyPI (via the command-line tool `pip`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this was a version-specific issue.  I upgraded to GDAL version 1.8.0 and the geotransform is set correctly.