# GDAL SetGeoTransform() issue

Tags: gdal

SetGeoReference it is not working with this code. (I think that I should need some more explanation on how this works...)

```
"""

Retrieve Georef & Projection from a reference image

"""

ReferenceTif = gdal.Open(img_path_tif)
GeoRef = ReferenceTif.GetGeoTransform() #I take the geo ref of the ref image
projRef = ReferenceTif.GetProjection()  #I take the proj as of the ref image

print(GeoRef)
(654000.0, 0.3, 0.0, 4203000.0, 0.0, -0.3)

"""

Set the Georef & Projection of a image

"""

test = gdal.Open('test.tif')            #Open a new image
test.SetProjection(proj)                #Set the projection like the ref image
test.SetGeoTransform(GeoRef)            #Set the GeoRef like the ref image

"""

Check if the work is done

"""

result = test.GetGeoTransform()         #Get the GeoRef of the test image
print(result==GeoRef)                   #Check if the work is done correctly
print(result)

False (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Test.SetProjection(proj) doesn't look right, should it be Test.SetProjection(projRef ) as projRef  is the object retrieved from ReferenceTif.GetProjection(). If this line is failing the next line isn't executed, which is the one you use to set the GeoTransform, change the object for SetProjection and see if that works.

Comment: Oh yes he should, I just change it but still the output is "False". 

Still it's not working :/ .. Any other idea ?

Comment: Maybe this can help:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165950/gdal-setgeotransform-does-not-work-as-expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very similar to this problem [How do I change a raster's geotransform with GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21746/how-do-i-change-a-rasters-geotransform-with-gdal) however I was getting the same error with the current version of GDAL on two workstations. The return code was 3 which I was unable to find a reference for, however [GDALDatasets opened or open shared](https://gdal.org/api/raster_c_api.html#gdal_8h_1a46a02c21047d78f88f8abb1ff6b14ae2) without GDALAccess set to [GDALAccess::GA_Update](https://gdal.org/doxygen/gdal_8h.html#a045e3967c208993f70257bfd40c9f1d7) implicitly are opened **read only** so the SetGeoTransform shouldn't have been able to change the geotransform of the dataset - this is likely a bug in GDAL.

If you change your code to:

```
test = gdal.OpenShared('test.tif',gdal.GA_Update))  #Open a new image for updating
test.SetProjection(proj)                            #Set the projection like the ref image
test.SetGeoTransform(GeoRef)                        #Set the GeoRef like the ref image
```

You will be able to apply the projection and spatial reference then set `test=None` to [close the dataset properly](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html#closing-the-dataset), this then worked for me on both workstations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help. 
I apply your advice @MichaelStimson and that's working perfectly. 
See you